# Writing a Java program that encrypts .txt files with an integer key

Tags: java, encryption

This is my first question on StackOverflow. Hope it's gonna be clear and detailed enough.

So I need to write 2 methods, encrypt and decrypt.
My encrypt function is:

```
 public void cifra() throws FileNotFoundException,IOException {

        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(file);
        String s="";
        int b;

        while(in.read()!=-1) {

            b=in.read()+key;
            s+=b;
        }

        in.close();

        PrintStream ps=new PrintStream(file);
        ps.println(s);

        ps.close();

 }
```

My decrypt function is the same but with

```
b=in.read()-key;
```

But it dont works. The output file is not same as the initial file non-crypted.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: For reference: this is a **caesar cipher**. Where are you struggling, what bytes are wrong, in what way? What is current input + output, vs. expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Change your while function to this:

```
while ((b = in.read()) != -1) {
    b += key;
    s += b;
}
```

Currently you read twice, first time inside while condition and second inside the loop, so you are skipping 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

in.read() is reading in a single byte of the file, as an integer. You are then converting that integer to a string via s+=b.

So say in.read() gives you 97 (ASCII for 'a') and your key is 5, you are turning around and writing literally 102 to the file, instead of an 'f', which would be the "encoded" character.

Your loop should be building a byte array (or byte stream) and you should write that byte array to the file.

Here are the docs for the [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), which your loop should write to, which you can in-turn write to a file.

Comment: thanks, i finally understood why my program wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading bytes (each one into an int).

A `String` however is not an array of bytes, but contains Unicode text, and can combine Greek, Chinese and whatever. (In fact `String` uses `char`s where every char is two `byte`s.) There is a conversion involved for the external bytes having some charset encoding. That will go wrong, uses more memory and is slow. Hence generally one does not use String here.

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int b;
while((b = in.read()) !=-1) {
    b = (b + key) % 256;
    out.write(b);
}
in.close();

byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
FileOutputStream out2 = new FileOutputStream(file);
out2.write(data);
out2.close();
```

The other problem is that bytes have a range 0 - 255 (or signed bytes -128 - 127).
Hence my `%`, modulo. one sees `& 0xFF` too (bitwise AND with 255, 0b1111_1111).

Note that `println(someInt)` will write a textual representation as an integer, 'A' being int 65 will be stored as "65" - to 2 bytes: 56 and 55.

Comment: Thanks I just updated my program and it works. Thanks for the explaination :)